# documents for J standard library stdlib.ijs

Tags: j

is there a detailed document or commented version of J's stdlib.ijs? The [Jwiki link](http://www.jsoftware.com/jwiki/stdlib.ijs) does not include much.  Are functions in stdlib.ijs for user use or only intended for internal use?

The local installation of copy stdlib.ijs has much more functions than [the onlline version](http://www.jsoftware.com/wsvn/base7/trunk/main/main/stdlib.ijs).

Comment: Geez. I really wish somebody else would answer. I'm now quite curious about all the functionality in the stdlib.ijs.

Answer (score 3):

Have you opened up [stdlib.ijs](http://www.jsoftware.com/wsvn/base7/trunk/main/main/stdlib.ijs) in the online Subversion repository? It has fairly generous commenting. For example, this is the entry for `boxopen`:

```
NB. =========================================================
NB.*boxopen v box argument if open
NB.-Box argument if open.
NB.- e.g. if script=: 0!:0 @ boxopen, then either
NB.-   script 'work.ijs'  or  script <'work.ijs'
NB.-
NB.-See also [boxxopen](boxxopen).
NB.-
NB.-Use [cutopen](#cutopen) to allow multiple arguments.
boxopen=: <^:(L.=0:)
```

That said, I wouldn't mind a better reference myself.

Comment: In my local installation of J801, the stdlib.ijs has much more functions and no comments?

Comment: I can't speak to J801, since that's in beta and I'm using J701. That said, my local copy has no comments in stdlib.ijs either. I linked to the online Subversion copy of stdlib.ijs, which is where you can find comments.

Comment: besides comments, did you find the local copy is longer than the online copy of stdlib.ijs and has more functions?

Comment: Ugh. There are 2338 lines in my local copy, and only 553 lines in the online one I linked to. The local copy doesn't include comments to boot.

Comment: Okay, now I really want to see if anybody has a better resource. I'm curious about all of the functionality in stdlib.ijs now.

Comment: The difference between the svn version and your local installation is that the local library has been processed by the J project manager, which will consolidate all the scripts in a package or addon into a single, compressed, stand-alone file. The intent is to maintain the organized, documented codebase in svn, and use package manager produce compact, stand-alone files for distribution (including stripping comments).

Comment: @DanBron: So, how do I find all of the files in svn that are consolidated into the stdlib.ijs? If ahala could find each of those files, he could presumably read the comments to learn more about the functionality included in stdlib.ijs.

Comment: I didn't know how to answer your question, until Bill Lam recently reminded me of the J user manual.  The part relevant to the standard library definitions is here:

http://www.jsoftware.com/help/user/library.htm

Answer (score 3):

According to the [J mailinglist](http://jsoftware.2058.n7.nabble.com/stdlib-documentation-td57664.html),

> Documentation of standard library of J8 is now available as a chapter
>   of the J User manual,
>
> - http://www.jsoftware.com/help/user/library.htm
>
> which is also part of the docs/help addons.